# Ionic push plugin error in installation

Tags: ionic-framework

When i tried to add ionic push plugin using 
    ***ionic plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git***
 i got following error in command promp

```
Updated the hooks directory to have execute permissions Fetching plugin "https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git" via git clone Repository "https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin.git" checked out to git  ref "master". shell.js: internal error Error: EXDEV, cross-device link not permitted 'C:\Users\A-25\AppData\Local\Temp\git\1438839071751\Example'
at Error (native)
at Object.fs.renameSync (fs.js:636:18)
at C:\Users\A-25\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\mv.js:77:8 at Array.forEach (native)
at Object._mv (C:\Users\A-25\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\mv.js:53:11)at Object.mv (C:\Users\A-25\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:186:23)
at C:\Users\A-25\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\util\plugins.js:53:19
at _fulfilled (C:\Users\A-25\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\A-25\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\A-25\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:749:13)
```

can anybody tell me what's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

i just downgrade my cordova version to 5.0.0 and it works

Answer (score 0):

Without downgrading your cordova version you could try this 
`ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-push-notification`

Answer (score 0):

I had a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32896700/ionic-plugin-add-phonegap-plugin-push-results-in-a-404-not-found-error/32896701#32896701):

From an [official blog post](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html), Cordova is moving their plugins to npm.

I had the same problem with the `ionic plugin add ...` command that Mudasser mentioned. So, I installed it easily now with npm:

```
npm install phonegap-plugin-push
```