# ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push results in a 404 Not Found Error

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I was following the official (and rather great) docs over at Ionic for [how to get started with push notifications](http://docs.ionic.io/v1.0/docs/push-from-scratch).

However, once the instructions said to install the phonegap-plugin-push plugin, I received the following error:

```
nikola@Nikolas-Mini ~/Desktop/ionicTesting/ionicPush
> ionic plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
Error: 404 Not Found: phonegap-plugin-push
at RegClient.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:304:14)
at Request._callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-registry-client/lib/request.js:246:65)
at Request.self.callback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:236:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:110:17)
at Request.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1142:14)
at Request.emit (events.js:129:20)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/request/request.js:1096:12)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:129:20)
at _stream_readable.js:908:16
at process._tickCallback (node.js:355:11)
```

Anyone has an idea of why? I tried with `cordova` instead `ionic` but I get the same error.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After quite some searching I stumbled upon an [official blog post](http://cordova.apache.org/announcements/2015/04/21/plugins-release-and-move-to-npm.html), Cordova is moving their plugins to npm.

So, finally, I installed it easily now with npm:

```
npm install phonegap-plugin-push
```

Comment: I think it should be `cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push`

Comment: Hmm, not quite sure as it could be due to temporary network error as well. You can try clearing the cache with `npm cache clean` (take a look at this question, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31547789/why-am-i-getting-unexpected-token-u0000-when-using-npm-install-g-package/31635673)

Comment: It appears to successfully install phone-gap-plugin, returning  `phonegap-plugin-push@1.5.3 node_modules/phonegap-plugin-push`--but if try to `ionic emulate` I still get the phonegap plugin error--specifically https://github.com/driftyco/ionic-platform-issues/issues/37. Totally stumped.